# Polkit and local serial consoles

Tags: serial-console, polkit

Are serial consoles considered local by `polkit`? Could that be configured e.g. via `/etc/securetty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've understood, a session is considered as *local* by `polkit` if it is associated with a local *seat*. By default, `seat0` is the only existing seat.

You can view the devices associated with a seat by e.g.:

```
loginctl seat-status seat0
```

To associate a device with a seat, it should have a udev tag `seat` added to it in udev rules.

You can view the udev tags of a device with e.g.:

```
udevadm info -q property --property=TAGS,CURRENT_TAGS -n /dev/ttyS0
```

By default, TTY devices (and thus serial consoles) don't seem to be associated with any seats, so a serial console login will be no different from a remote SSH login, as far as `polkit` is concerned.

Comment: Thanks. So polkit follows systemd’s semantics about serial consoles being intrinsically non-local. (interesting github issue btw: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8582)

Comment: It seems to me that having something like `pkttyagent` run in the background in a TTY-based session would require that session to also have some kind of input/output multiplexer similar to `screen` or `tmux`, and the authentication agent would have to be able to use that to seamlessly interrupt whatever is going on the session when needed. That would be a rather fundamental change to a classic TTY-based session setup. Sure it would be doable, but would be a big hurdle to get it widely accepted.